# Ubuntu LiveUSB boots to black screen after grub

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I have a LiveUSB with Ubuntu 18.04 which I want to use to install Ubuntu onto my laptop, a Lenovo Yoga 720-13IKB Signature Edition currently running Windows 10. Whenever I try to boot my laptop to the liveusb, I can see the screen that has "Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu", and others, but the screen just goes black and stays black permanently.

I know this can't be because of a faulty LiveUSB because I can use it on other computers and it works perfectly well.

I've tried all of the suggestions for how to fix it I can find online. I've tried adding in either `nomodeset` or `nomodeset nolapic` into the boot options, as well as a few other tweaks there that people recommended, placing it before, instead of, or after the `quiet splash`. I've tried every UEFI tweak I can find (secure boot off, SATA controller as either RAID or AHCI, legacy mode, etc.). I've tried everything listed here, but none of it seems to work for me.

What other problems exist that could potentially cause it to not advance past a black screen? I'm starting to suspect it's some hardware or firmware issue specific to my computer, so anyone with experience on my specific model would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue. In the UEFI settings, under `Boot`, there is a setting which needs to be chanced. The setting defaults to `UEFI`, but you have to change it to `Legacy Mode`.

Comment: This is not a solution, OP changed boot mode from UEFI to CSM, The live USB is supposed to boot in UEFI, read this -> https://superuser.com/a/1113787